# How to prevent submit last questionof a form if there is no answer

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, submit

I have a form of a survey with questions. First I hide all questions and I show one after another with button Next. I've made validation and it works but only for the last question it is not working. I've provided also Php validation if someone doesn't have JavaScript enabled. Now when you have not chosen an answer for the last question,it does not submit form, but it returns to the first question of survey and you have to choose them again. That's my problem - how to validate last quesion? Here's my code:

```
$(function () {
    $( document ).ready(hideAllRows);
    $( document ).ready(showFirst);
    $('#button').hide();
});

function hideAllRows(){
    $('#questionsTable tr').each(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
}

$(function () {
    $("#next").click(showNextQuestion);
});

var currentInd = 1;
var prevInd = 1;
function showNextQuestion(){
    $(function () {
        var indId = "#"+currentInd;
        prevInd = currentInd - 1;
        var prevId = "#"+prevInd;

        //validation
        var isAnyClicked = false;​
        if ($(prevId + " input[type='radio']:checked").val()) {
            isAnyClicked = true;
        }

        if(currentInd > 0 && currentInd  != $('#questions_count').val() && isAnyClicked == false) {
            alert('Моля, отговорете!');
        }

        else {
            //hide previous question
            $(prevId).hide();

            //show next question 
            var indId = "#"+currentInd;
            $(indId).show();
            currentInd++;
            if(currentInd  == $('#questions_count').val()) {
                $('#button').show();
                $("#next").hide();
            }
        }
    });
}

function showFirst(){
    $(function () {
        $('#0').each(function() {
            $(this).show();
        });
    });
}
```

.

```
<?php

$att=array('id'=>'form');
echo form_open('index/survey_fill/' .$survey_id .'/'. $question_id , $att); ?>
<input type='hidden' name='questions_count' id='questions_count' value='<?php echo count($question); ?>' />
<table id='questionsTable' >
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Question</th></tr>
  </thead>   
  <tbody>
  <?php
    echo validation_errors();​
 $index = 0;
    foreach ($question as $row)
    {
        echo "<tr id='$index'>";
        $index++;
    ?>

        <td> 
        <?php echo "$row->question"; ?><br/>
        <?php echo "<input type='hidden' name='question_id' value='$row->question_id' />"; ?>
        <?php 

        $data=array(
            'name' =>  'answer['.$row->question_id.']',
            'value' => '5',
            'class' => 'answer'

        );

        echo "<input type='hidden' name='survey_id' value='$row->survey_id'>"; 

        echo form_radio($data); 
        echo " 5 ";
        $data=array(
            'name' =>  'answer['.$row->question_id.']',
            'value' => '4',
            'class' => 'answer'
        );
        echo form_radio($data);​
         echo "4";
</td></tr>

    <?php 
    }

?>      

</table>
 <?php echo "<input type='hidden' name='question_id' value='$row->question_id' />"; ?>
  <?php  echo '<input type="submit" id="button" name = "submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success">';
  ?>
<input type="button" id="next" name = "next" value="Next" class="btn btn-success">
</form>
</div>

</body>​
```

I tried with this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var currentInd=1;      
    $('form').on('submit', function(e){
        isAnyClicked = false;

        if (currentInd  = $('#questions_count').val() &&
                ($(currentInd + " input[type='radio']:checked").val())) {
             isAnyClicked = true;
             $(currentInd ).hide();
             alert(" answer selected");
        } if (currentInd  = $('#questions_count').val() && isAnyClicked == false)  {    
            $('tr' + currentInd).css({ display: 'block' });

             e.preventDefault();
             alert("select answer");
             currentInd++;
         } 
    });
});​
```

It prevents form submit, but even I have selected answer, form does not submit. How to make first condition if you have chosen answer, form to subit? It always run second condition and form does not submit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prevent form to be submitted with following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form').on('submit', function(e){
    // validation code here
    if(!AllFieldsAreValid) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

You can define AllFieldsAreValid as True or False when all fields are filled correctly or not.

Comment: Form does not send, but it shows me again first question. How to stay on the last question in my case? Last question is when if( currentInd  = $('#questions_count').val()) { I can't do validation for it.

Comment: I could not to find where foreach ($question as $row){ is ended }. I think you can write all code with PHP and visible HTML codes. then using of Jquery for hide/show unneeded sections.

Comment: I edited my question. Now form does not submit even you have chosen some answer of last question. How to do form to submit if you have chosen some answer of last question? :)

Comment: I think <input type='hidden' name='question_id'  must be inserted into foreach loop. So at each looping question id must be changed. Here it is fixed ant could not be changed for each row.

Comment: It is also in foreach after <?php echo "$row->question"; ?><br/>
. Problem here now is that even when you choose answer, it doesn't submit form. I think this if does not run: if( currentInd  = $('#questions_count').val() && ($(currentInd + " input[type='radio']:checked").val())) {
        
          isAnyClicked = true;
          $(currentInd ).hide();
    alert(" answer");
    
  }

Comment: You must add return true;   after last if . Please use http://jsfiddle.net/ for html part (produced by PHP) and jquery or javascript. So please send link here for more details.